# Color irregular shaped paths in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, ios, core-graphics, quartz-graphics

What I want to do is color an irregular shape when user touch within that path.
Same as flood fill. But I found that flood fill is too costly in case of performance/speed/memory. So I have an idea. I dont know how to implement it. CGContextFillPath fills an irregular shapes.

So my Question is can we get a bounding paths/border line of that shape so that we can color that region??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you have an image with a shape in it, where all the pixels in the shape are one color, and the boundary of the shape is a different color.

If I understand you correctly, you would have to use a flood-fill algorithm to find the boundary of the shape so you could turn that boundary into a `CGPath`.  There's no magic way to get a path for the boundary of the shape without looking at the pixels.